# Play different sounds on each channel

Tags: linux, audio

Is there a way, preferably on Linux, of having two sounds playing at the same time, with each of them playing in a different channel?
If so, is it possible to do it on the fly?

Comment: What are the source of the sounds?

Comment: Browser windows, for instance.

Comment: Do you use pulseaudio? If so you can probably control which channel the audio is sent to.

Comment: How do I check for that?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Debian Testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pavucontrol` to control the volume and output channel of individual audio sources. This includes different audio sources within a browser. Install with

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Then open and the various audio sources should be listed in the Playback section. Note: the volume slider is locked on both channels, so you have to click the lock button to unlock them first; then you can turn the volume of the audio to the different channels up and down independently.